# FTP File Download times out using wget

Tags: ftp, wget

I am trying to download a file located at an FTP server. I am able to download the file manually through the browser but the download times out when I use wget for the same.

Can anyone help me with this problem

```
wget --ftp-user=user_name --ftp-password=password ftp://url/file_name.zip
```

Log:

```
--2014-12-09 08:37:34--  ftp://url/file_name.zip
       => `file_name.zip'
Resolving url (url)... x.x.x.x
Connecting to url(url)|x.x.x.x|:x... connected.
Logging in as user_name ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD not needed.
==> SIZE file_name.zip ... 15582845
==> PASV ... couldn't connect to 10.0.3.33 port 12185: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

> ==> PASV ... couldn't connect to 10.0.3.33 port 12185: Connection timed out

The server reports a private IP address as a response to the PASV command. I assume that the server is not inside your private network but instead in another private network behind a NAT router. In this case PASV is only possible if all necessary ports get forwarded to the server by the router and if the server reports the external address (of the router) instead of the internal address.

Some clients work around such badly configured servers by ignoring the IP address given as response to passive and using only the given port together with the public IP of the server. Or they don't use `PASV` but instead `EPSV` where the server does not return an IP address at all, but only the port.

Comment: so is there any alternative method I can download the file

Comment: According to your description it works with the browser, so you already have an alternative method.

Comment: I mean are there any alternate options to download the file from the terminal because I need to do the same on my server.

Comment: If the server has a public IP you might try active mode (might be blocked by firewall) or use EPSV instead of PASV  or have some client which ignores the IP send by the server. I don't know which clients do that. The best would be of course to fix the server.

Answer (score 0):

if your ftp server is **proftp** and behind a **nat network**,please in proftpd.conf add your server limit port:

> PassivePorts 8000 9000

PassivePorts command -- Specify the ftp-data port range to be used

this work for me.